# Asynctask para un onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Quiero meter este onActivityResult en un Asynctask

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            DropInResult result = data.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
            PaymentMethodNonce nonce = result.getPaymentMethodNonce();

            String strNonce = nonce.getNonce();
            if(grandTotal != null) {
                paramHash = new HashMap<>();
                paramHash.put("amount", grandTotal);
                paramHash.put("nonce", strNonce);
                paramHash.put("carritox_order_number", "HHAG PRUEBA");

                sendPayment();

                String datosDeCompra = "";
                // Terminar proceso
                CrearOrden("banktransfer");
                datosDeCompra = CrearFactura(new JSONObject());
                CrearEnvio();


                // Mostrar factura en pantalla
                try {
                    verCompra(new JSONObject(datosDeCompra));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor ingrese un monto válido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("HHAG", "Por favor ingrese un monto válido");

            }
        }
    }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Log.d("HHAG","Operación cancelada...!");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Operación cancelada...!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ocurrio un error...!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Exception error = (Exception)data.getSerializableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT);
        Log.d("HHAG_ERROR",error.toString());
    }
}
```

Porque alli tarda mucho en responder porque hace muchas peticiones REST. En este activity tengo agregado un progressbar que es el que quiero que aparezca mientras piensa para mostrarme la factura

No entiendo mucho como hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor explicá un poco mejor que querés hacer porque el método en sí no se puede poner en un asyncTask dado que es un callback del Activity. Por favor detallá si lo que debe ejecutarse en segundo plano es algo puntual que está dentro de onActivityResult().

Comment: Deseo que cuando se este ejecutando aparezca un progressbar para que despues me muestre lo que sigue, lo que quiero es que mientras este pensando la pantalla no quede como sino estuviese haciendo nada sino que aparezca algo como que ella esta pensando

Comment: Perdoname pero sigo sin entender cual es la parte que se debe ejecutar en segundo plano. Y me queda la duda de si lo que se ejecuta en segundo plano no es lo que viene antes de onActivityResult.

Comment: quisiera que se ejucute en segundo plano esto String datosDeCompra = "";
                // Terminar proceso
                CrearOrden("banktransfer");
                datosDeCompra = CrearFactura(new JSONObject());
                CrearEnvio();


                // Mostrar factura en pantalla
                try {
                    verCompra(new JSONObject(datosDeCompra));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }